# axvline on a specific date - weekly data

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, axvline

I'm trying to create a vertical line on specific date, which is not part of my df weekly date index,
and since it's not in the index, the plot is locating the vertical line on the next date that in the df index:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('2020-01-01','2020-05-01',freq='W'),data={'val':range(0,17)})
ax=df.plot(grid=True,figsize=(12,6))
ax.set_xticks(df.index)
ax.set_xticklabels([x.date() for x in df.index],rotation=90)
ax.axvline(pd.Timestamp('2020-03-03'),ls='--',color='k')
```

[image]

as you can see, although I want to draw the line on '2020-03-03', it's created on '2020-03-08'.

Any ideas here?
thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried simply adding "2020-03-03" to your sample? As you could easily interpolate the y value.

Comment: I need this for something more complicated that will be hard to interpolate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this using matplotlib instead of pandas plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig,ax=plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(12,6))
ax.plot(df)

ax.set_xticks(df.index)
ax.set_xticklabels([x.date() for x in df.index],rotation=90)
ax.axvline(pd.Timestamp('2020-03-03'),ls='--',color='k')
```

[image]